# How to remove app which fails to upgrade?

Tags: office-365

I'm having trouble removing an app I developed. I installed the first version to our intranet on Office 365 and when I deployed updated version it failed. Retrying installation also fails. Now I realised I don't even have an option to remove the app altogether. I'm an administrator on the site.
How do I remove this app or how do I get it to upgrade successfully?

Note: it's a simple app - a couple of custom lists and pages.

[image: No option to remove app]

Comment: Click on "Click to retry" and try to delete your application.

Comment: Tried that too, it keeps failing, still not button to remove. Also tried to remove it from app catalogue and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

the option is not coming because you are not added to 'Site Owners' group. Its strange that even if you have admin access on site, you still need to be in Site owners group to remove the app.

Answer (score 0):

f you no longer need an app on your site, you can remove it by going to the Site Contents page.

IMPORTANT    After you remove an app, you will not be able to recover any data that the app may be storing in the location where it is hosted. If you want to keep this data, you must save it before you remove the app. Go to the app you plan to remove, and manually copy the data to another format (some apps may provide you with a way to export data).

To remove an app, you must have Full Control permissions for a SharePoint site. If you are a Site Owner, you have this permission.

- Go to Settings Settings button > Site Contents.
- On the Site Contents page, find the app you want to remove and click
  the ellipses (. . .) to view the app properties callout.
- In the callout, click the ellipses (. . .) and then click Remove on
  the menu.

[image]

- Click OK

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/remove-an-app-from-a-site-HA103022226.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102772361

Comment: OP mentions that Remove option is not available.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do... but there's no Remove context menu item, there isn't even an elipsis to get to that menu (see my screenshot). Trust me, I did read the relevant page on microsoft.com.